# How can I adjust the vertical datum of cross section coordinates in a spreadsheet?

Tags: hec-ras

So I was able to get really detailed lidar cross-sections from this [tool](https://equatorstudios.com/hec-ras-cross-sections/), but I am not sure how to make use of it in my model.  The vertical datum doesn't seem to match up.

Is there an easy way to adjust the vertical datum for a bunch of coordinates in a spreadsheet?  I am going to try QGIS, but I am not super experienced in it.  Curious if anyone has come across anything simple that could help.

A sample of my section is included for reference.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: what do you mean by the "vertical datum"

Answer (score 1):

You can convert between vertical datums using vDatum.  vDatum is free and opensource software developed by USA NOAA. vDatum is offered as a OS independent Java executable so you will need to have a Java interpreter installed on your computer. The correct transformations may not be available to you if you are outside of the USA and your vertical datum are location specific.  Common transformations between WGS84 elipsoids or geoids,  NAD 83, NAD27, or between tidal datums are all valid inputs for vDatum.

You will not be able to use your spreadsheet as stated.  You will need to convert your data to a [format acceptable](https://vdatum.noaa.gov/docs/userguide.html#step31) to vDatum.

You will  need to determine the vertical datum of your LiDAR Z data but that is typically included in the LiDAR report.

Next you will want to determine what vertical datum you want to convert to (and why).  You mention that your z values do not 'match up'.  Match up to what? Some antiquated surface model?  Please specify what you are comparing your LiDAR cross section z values to.

[See here](https://vdatum.noaa.gov/docs/datums.html) for a tutorial on vertical datums.

Answer (score 0):

HEC-RAS actually also has a [vertical datum adjustment](https://www.hec.usace.army.mil/confluence/rasdocs/rasum/latest/entering-and-editing-geometric-data/geometric-data-tools/vertical-datum-adjustment) option
If you also need to adjust the horizontal datum / coordinate reference / projection you can [do that in HEC-RAS 5 or 6](https://www.kleinschmidtgroup.com/ras-post/re-projecting-hec-ras-model-geometry/) as well - it uses the same GDAL library that QGIS does.